# How to find correlation between 3 signals

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis, ifft

I have 3 signals, S1 S2 S3, with a same time domain and same time steps. I'm wondering if there is any correlation between these 3 signals. more specifically I want to know if it is possible to make Signal S3 by any combination of signals S1 and S2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to process them jointly in pairs to get the correlation coefficients
$$\rho_{13}=\frac{\mathsf{Cov}(S_1,S_3)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(S_1)\mathsf{Var}(S_3)}}$$
$$\rho_{23}=\frac{\mathsf{Cov}(S_2,S_3)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(S_2)\mathsf{Var}(S_3)}}$$ that represent the linear dependencies between $S_1$, $S_3$ and $S_2$, $S_3$, respectively. So when $|\rho_{xy}|$ is close to one, it indicates high linear dependency (and values close to zero mean small linear dependency).

That said, the problem you mentioned can be solved using a least squares approximation. In MATLAB, assuming your signals are in form of column vectors `S1`, `S2`, and `S3`, you can do this to find the weights:

```
w = [S1 S2]\S3;
```

So the signal `S3` can be approximated as

```
S3_hat = [S1 S2]*w;
```

and the mean squared approximation error is

```
mse_err = mse(S3-S3_hat);
```